# USB connections, which is the most common and reliable?

Tags: usb

I've found a lot of different ways to connect USB power and D+ D- in EVBoards and other kind of boards.

I've summarized this ways in this schematic:

[image]

(Right click and open image to zoom)

As you can see I will not use ID pin, board will be powered from usb just for trasfer data with D+ and D-.

I'm looking for a general and good way to wire USB so I want to ask, is this a correct connection? What I can remove and what I should add?

Comment: Whether or not you need the 68R series termination or 1k5 pullup resistors will depend on the IC you're using. C76 seems to be connected to GND on both sides ...

Comment: What about inductor? are they really necessary?